# How to solve for the competitive equilibrium in this very lopsided model?

Tags: uncertainty

Suppose there's an infinite-horizon pure-exchange economy with 2 agents. Utility function for both agents is
$$u(c)=\frac{c^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}$$
The state at $t\geq 0$ is a random variable, $s_t$, with realization in $S=\{0,1\}$. The agents' endowments are
$$\epsilon_t^1=\epsilon_t^2=\frac{1}{2},t=0,1$$
$$\epsilon_t^1=s_t,\epsilon_t^2=1-s_t,t\geq 2$$
The state is a Markov process: $\pi(s_0=1),\pi_1(s_1=1|s_0=1),\pi_2(s_2=1|s_1=1)=\pi_2(s_2=0|s_1=1)=\frac{1}{2},\pi_t(s_t=1|s_{t-1}=1)=1,\pi_t(s_t=0|s_{t-1}=0)=1$.

That is, at $t=0,1$, each agent gets $\frac{1}{2}$ of endowments. At $t=2,$ either agent 1 gets 1 endowment and agent 2 gets 0 endowment or agent 1 gets 0 endowment and agent 2 gets 1 endowment. Both events occur with probability 0.5. From $t=3$ and onwards, the agents will continue getting the same endowments as they did at $t=2$.

How can I solve the Arrow-Debreu competitive equilibrium? Here's what I've got so far:
\begin{align*}
&\max \sum_{t=0}^\infty \sum_{s^t}\beta^t\frac{c_t^i(s^t)^{1-\sigma}}{1-\sigma}\cdot\pi_t(s^t)\\
&\text{s.t. }\sum_{t=0}^\infty \sum_{s^t} p_t(s^t)c_t^i(s^t)\leq\sum_{t=0}^\infty \sum_{s^t}p_t(s^t)\epsilon_t^i(s^t)
\end{align*}
By Lagrange, I got
$$\frac{c_t^2(s^t)}{c_t^1(s^t)}=\left(\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sigma}}$$
where $\mu_i$ is the multiplier. Then I realized, if i continue like this, then the bizarre lopsided endowment doesn't play a role here. Could someone point me to the right direction?